# MySQLi insert into statement inserts data but also shows errors

Tags: php, insert, mysqli

Going out of my mind on this one.  Here's the situation and what I've tried so far:

I've got a simple form that collects an email and a password which are then supposed to be inserted into a database table with three columns.  The table is called `users` and the three columns are called `userID`, `userEmail`, `userPassword`.  Here is my starting code:

```
// hash the password value
$pass = hash_hmac('sha256', $p, 'c#hArl891', true);

// Query the database:
$q = "INSERT INTO users (userEmail, userPassword) VALUES ('".$e."','".$pass."')";       
$r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);

if (mysqli_num_rows($r) == 1) { // Successful insertion.
```

What happened with this code is that the email (variable `$e`) showed up correctly in the database and the password was a garbled mess (a side issue) but the `mysqli_num_rows($r)` returned this error:

```
mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given
```

I've tried replacing the hashed value with just $p, I've tried replacing both variables with constants, I've tried using back-ticks around the table name and field names, and I've tried a suggestion I found online to use braces:

```
$q = "INSERT INTO users (`userEmail`,`userPassword`) VALUES ('{$e}','{$pass}')";
```

Nothing seems to work to get `mysqli_num_rows($r) == 1`.

According to the returned error message, I'm seeing variable values of:

```
[e] => webmaster@brukenet.com
[p] => 12345
[pass] => Ç o’,YÊ2ý€|y:fØ²"?ïÑ`{a]YÑ=Âk¼
[q] => INSERT INTO `users` (`userEmail`, `userPassword`) VALUES ('webmaster@brukenet.com', 'Ç o’,YÊ2ý€|y:fØ²"?ïÑ`{a]YÑ=Âk¼') 
[r] => 1
```

and

```
[dbc] => mysqli Object
```

These would seem to indicate that `$r` DOES equal `1` but this is taken directly from the same error message.

I've been up all night and I'm thinking this must be something obvious that I'm just over-looking but I just can't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert queries don't return a result set and you can only use `mysqli_num_rows()` on a result set.

Try doing

```
if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) > 0) {
```

As for your hashing issue, are you sure you want to store the raw binary output? Change the `true` to `false` in your `hash_hmac()` function or use `bin2hex()` on your raw binary data to get some readable data.

Comment: That fixed the primary problem; the error message is gone and I'm able to get the conditional to trigger correctly.  Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you for that hash info also. I'd mark the issue correct twice if I could.  Much appreciated.